# cardCornerRadius проблемка

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview

**Что за непрозрачные уголочки? Как пофиксить?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="18dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_alertsave"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Название списка"
                android:textColor="#B3ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FAFAFA"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alertEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:backgroundTint="#4D000000"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#B3000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#FD8086"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Вы карточку внутри диалогфрагмента показываете? Наверняка, его фон.

Comment: @Peter Samokhin, при вызове в acivity - то же самое, углы видно

Comment: а какой класс для диалога используете?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте эту строчку в коде
`alertDialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`